# USB Wireless adapters enabling Power Saving Mode

Tags: wifi, access-point, power-saving, chipset

I am being confused on all terminology referring to it, so here is my request:

Name at least one **USB Wireless Adapter** whose **Wi-Fi chipset** is supported by a **wireless driver** enabling **AP mode**, **Monitor Mode** and  **PSM (Power Saving Mode)** in a **SoftMAC implementation** (PSM functions accessible and modifiable via software).

The goal is to work on a new Power Saving Mode implementation, by modifying existing implementations of either PSM or APSM.

Comment: The answer seems to be: None (at least no open-source driver fully support PSM).

Answer (score 0):

Check out MediaTek USB dongles:
http://www.mediatek.com/en/products/connectivity/wifi/pc/usb/

Most of these can work straight away using Linux mainline rt2x00 driver. rt2x00 is open-source, supports Monitor mode (can sniff packets), AP mode (can work with wpa_supplicant/hostapd), and is a SoftMAC driver (as it works with mac80211 driver). As for PSM, I'm not sure although there seems to be a good chance that rt2x00 supports it as well..